# cakephp, select for a form are generated with a query

Tags: forms, select, cakephp-1.3

I have this query in the controller

```
$clientslist = $this->Client->query("SELECT client_name FROM clients WHERE active=1");
```

how can i show my clients list with a select in a form?

```
echo $this->Form->input('clientname', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => ??????));
```

thanks

---

**EDIT**

i've solved my problem

in controller

```
$clientslist = $this->Client->find('list', array('fields' => array('Client.client_name'), 'conditions' => array('Client.active' => '1')));
        $this->set('clientslist', $clientslist);
```

in view

```
echo $this->Form->input('cliente', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $clientslist));
```

i have another problem now

in view the value of every option of the selectbox is the id
how can i use the name of the client in the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you query to the following:

```
$clientslist = $this->Client->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Client.active' => '1')));
```

This will automatically build an option list of `ID, NAME` for use in the select box.

Comment: with my query i get `<option value="4">Apple</option>`, with yours i get `<option value="4">4</option>`   but i need `<option value="Apple">Apple</option>`